# Can the number of duplicates in a large set be estimated by knowing the number of duplicates in a smaller (but still large) subset?

Tags: statistics

This question generally deals with estimating the number of duplicates in a large set by examining a random sample of a smaller (but still large) subset.

I've tried to formalize the question a bit below. But it's also been a while since my last formal math class, so I realize that what follows is not actually "formalized."

Consider:

A set M of different integers.

A superset of M, called N, which is identical to M except that some members of M appear more than once (they are "duplicated").

A subset of N, called P, which is comprised of a random sample of the members of N.

A subset of P, called Q, which is identical to P except that all duplicates in P only appear once.

For example, M might be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], N might be [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], and P might be [2, 2, 4, 5]. Q would be [2, 4, 5].

M, N, P, and Q are all very large, but P is an order of magnitude smaller than N.

You know that N is of size n, that P is of size p, and that Q is of size q. But you do not know the size of M, and nor can you examine N to "de-duplicate" it and find the size of M.

You can easily calculate the “duplicate rate” of P: $$D(P)=\frac{p-q}p$$

You want to know the duplicate rate of N: $$D(n)=\frac{n-m}n$$

More importantly, and since the size of M is unknown, you want to know whether D(N) is greater than, equal to, or less than D(P).

My intuition is that $D(N)=D(P)$. But my intuition frequently fails me in statistics, and I would like either others' intuition, or a more formal answer and explanation.

Comment: When you draw $P$ from $N$, is it without replacement?  That would mean that if you get a duplicate in $P$ it is duplicated in $N$.  That seems to be the reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't even be equal in expectation, but you can learn some things.  Let's think about some limiting cases.  One would be that $N$ consists only of (not many) pairs and singletons, so $D(N)$ is a rather small number.  There are then $n-m$  pairs and $2m-n$ singletons.  The chance that a specific element is drawn is $\frac pn$.  The chance that both elements of a given pair are drawn is $\frac {p(p-1)}{n(n-1)} \approx \frac {p^2}{n^2}$ so the expected number of pairs in your draw is $(n-m)\frac {p^2}{n^2}$.  If you assume that the composition is this, you can scale up the observed number of pairs to the expected number of pairs by multiplying by $\frac {n^2}{p^2}$  Another composition would be if $N$ consists of lots of copies of relatively few different elements.  In that case you are sampling the density of each type.  You will likely have seen all the types, but it will be impossible to say there isn't some (or a few) singletons in the mix.